# How should I build my Java code using Hibernate(JPA) with Gradle?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, gradle

I'm very new with Hibernate(JPA).

Here is the related version info: *Java 8, Gradle 4.0, Hibernate 5.3.2.Final*.

I have a problem that my unit test(JUnit) failed when build it with Gradle.

I have some test codes and surely it passes when run it on Eclipse, but it is failed when run with Gradle(`./gradlew build`).

I found the following QA on SO and I could pass my test with Gradle using this solution with a warning message.

[java - Hibernate with Tomcat and gradle - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22972947/hibernate-with-tomcat-and-gradle)

This answer suggests to add the following setting to build.gradle.

```
sourceSets.all {
    output.resourcesDir = output.classesDir
}
```

The warning message is the following.

```
> Configure project :
Gradle now uses separate output directories for each JVM language, but this build assumes a single directory for all classes from a source set. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0
```

As you can see, this workaround will be failed when Gradle goes 5.0.

So, I want to ask you **how should I build my codes with Hibernate and Gradle.**

According to some SO's QA, I tried to add the following dependency, but it does not work.

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.1-api', version: '1.0.2.Final'
```

- [hibernate - Gradle compileJpaModelgenJava FAILED - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998178/gradle-compilejpamodelgenjava-failed#42069879)
- [Maven Repository: org.hibernate.javax.persistence » hibernate-jpa-2.1-api » 1.0.2.Final](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.2.Final)

Also, I found Hibernate Gradle Plugin, so I added it to the dependency, but it does not work too.

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-gradle-plugin', version: '5.3.2.Final'
```

[Maven Repository: org.hibernate » hibernate-gradle-plugin » 5.3.2.Final](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-gradle-plugin/5.3.2.Final)

Here is a portion of my directory Structure.

```
.
├── README.md
├── build.gradle
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── xxxxx
        │           └── xxxxx
        │               └── api
        │                   ├── dao
        │                   │   └── JpaDao.class
        │                   └── dto
        │                       └── Tasks.java
        ├── resources
        │   ├── META-INF
        │   │   └── persistence.xml
        │   └── hibernate.properties
        └── webapp
            ├── index.html
            └── v1-docs
                └── index.html
```

Portion of my build.gradle file is the following:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

def defaultEncoding = 'UTF-8'
tasks.withType(AbstractCompile).each {
  it.options.encoding = defaultEncoding
}
tasks.withType(GroovyCompile).each {
  it.groovyOptions.encoding = defaultEncoding
}
[compileJava, compileTestJava].each {
  it.options.compilerArgs += ['-source', '1.8', '-target', '1.8']
}

repositories {
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {
  compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.3.2.Final'
  testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

sourceSets.all {
    output.resourcesDir = output.classesDir
}
```

My Entity, i.e. Tasks class(this class name shows up on my error output), is the following:

```
@Entity
public class Tasks {

    @Id
    public UUID id;

    @Column(name = "is_finished")
    public boolean isFinished;

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    public Timestamp updatedAt;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    public String userId;
}
```

My JPA calling code is the following:

```
EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
TypedQuery<Tasks> query = em
        .createQuery("SELECT task FROM Tasks task WHERE task.userId = :userId", Tasks.class)
        .setParameter("userId", userId);
tasksDtoList = query.getResultList();
em.close();
```

And error output is the following(bit a long, but I'm not sure where is the important clue to resolve):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Tasks is not mapped [SELECT task FROM Tasks task WHERE task.userId = :userId]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:715)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:731)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
    at com.soybs.taskrtomato.api.dao.JpaDao.getTaskList(JpaDao.java:54)
    at com.soybs.taskrtomato.api.service.UserServiceTest.test(UserServiceTest.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:146)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:128)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Tasks is not mapped [SELECT task FROM Tasks task WHERE task.userId = :userId]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:706)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Tasks is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3695)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3584)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:720)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:576)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:191)
    ... 57 more
```

Comment: Do you have Tasks table in your database?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse. That's why JUnit test on Eclipse is succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could resolve it with the following config on `build.gradle`.

```
sourceSets {
  java {
    main {
      output.resourcesDir = java.outputDir
    }
  }
}
```

See also: SourceSetOutput - Gradle DSL Version 5.5 https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.html

Comment: how in the world would we know to add what looks like completely arbitrary code to build.gradle to get hibernate to work. other then reading the docs for 5 hours... thanks tkhm for following up